# "Periodical" ACF

Tags: r, time-series

I'm working with a time series data set in R. I've removed the trend and the seasonality but the ACF of the residuals has a "periodical" shape:

[image]

[image]

What does this mean? I've tried with both a multiplicative model and an additive model. I'm trying to identify what ARIMA process my time series could correspond to.

I'm sorry if the question seems trivial, it's my first time trying to make data fit a model.

Answer (score 1):

First, when inspecting the ACF and PACF plots that may indicate multiple AR and/or MA model parameters the initial plots seem incomprehensible. This is the case with the two graphs.

Second, model the obvious parameter first. Then examine the ACF and the PACF of the residuals which has the effect of the first parameter removed to identify any other necessary parameters. This step by step modeling peals away the complexity

In the case above, the first obvious parameter is an AR(1) as evidenced by the spike in the PACF at lag(1). If the estimated AR(1) parameter is greater than .8, then the series is not stationary. If this is the case, begin again using first differences.

Venturing a guess, the spike in the PACF at lag 12 may indicate the need for an AR(12) term, but do not include this term until the spike in the PACF at lag(12) remains after modeling with the AR(1) parameter. Disregard the significant spikes at lags 11 and 13. These are likely harmonics.